# "father to" vs. "father of"

Tags: expressions, differences, prepositions

Would it be grammatically correct to write

> Mister X is father **to** a son and a daughter

or should one preferably choose the preposition *of*?

> Mister X is father **of** a son and a daughter.

If both are correct, is there a difference in meaning? Could a step-dad perhaps only say that he is "father **to** a son" but not ***of*** him, if he is not the son's biological father (along the lines of expressions like "he is like a father *to* me")?

Is there any reference in BE/AE with respect to "father **to**" vs. "father **of**"?

Comment: Both are correct, grammatically as well as in meaning and usage, no matter if one is a biological father or otherwise. However, there's a difference in meaning. The preposition *to* focuses on the relationship, while *of* focuses on the subject (-object pair). "He is like a father **to** me (not *of* me)."

Comment: Right. I see that the usage of "to" in "like a father to me" is not governed by "father" but by "is". You're right. Is there any reference in BE/AE with respect to "father to" vs. "father of"?

Comment: *Father of a son* sounds idiomatic and colloquial. *Father to a son* sounds rather formal and detached. *Like a father to me* is a different usage.

Comment: I think neither is correct because you need an article before the word father.  "Mister X is a father to a son", or "Mister X is the father of a son".

Comment: @andi No article is required; we are relating a role, not an identity, like *she is prime minister of Italy* or *he is head coach of the Cincinnati Bengals.*

Comment: @choster That may be true with _to_, but “He is father of a son” is completely and utterly ungrammatical to me. “She is prime minister of Italy” is clumsy as well to me. Only “He is head coach of the Cincinnati Bengals” is acceptable, and even there it fails with a non-definite prepositional object: “He is head coach of a local swimming team” jars, too.

Answer (score -1):

I appears that the pragmatics owe to the classification of the prepositions.

*of* is a preposition of possession:

> Father **of** a son

--> "belongs to" or "relates to" *cf* "members of the family"

*to* is a preposition of value:

> Father **to** a son

*cf* "What does that matter **to** me?" --> "What is its value to me?"

---

*Caveat*: "Most common adpositions are highly polysemous (they have various different meanings). In many cases a primary, spatial meaning becomes extended to non-spatial uses by metaphorical or other processes." [Preposition and postposition – 7 Semantic functions (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_and_postposition#Semantic_functions)